# Infinite scroll listview inside AccordionView in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, accordion

I am trying this accordion control to display the ListItems with infinite scroll listview inside each segment of accordion.

**Accordion View Control:**
https://github.com/Kimserey/AccordionView

**Xamarin.Forms Infinite Scrolling ListView:**

http://15mgm15.ghost.io/2017/11/28/implement-an-infinite-scrolling-listview-with-xamarin-forms/

I need to implement this control using xaml, but I am getting exception while implementing.

```
<StackLayout>
            <local:AccordionView ItemsSource="{Binding ListItem}">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:AccordionView.Template>
                        <local:AccordionView.SubTemplate>
                            <ListView
                                CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding ListItem.Items}">
                                <ListView.Behaviors>
                                    <scroll:InfiniteScrollBehavior />
                                </ListView.Behaviors>

                                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                                <!-- the "loading..." view, with visibility bound to IsWorking -->
                                <ListView.Footer>
                                    <Grid Padding="4" IsVisible="{Binding IsLoadingMore}">
                                        <!-- set the footer to have a zero height when invisible -->
                                        <Grid.Triggers>
                                            <Trigger TargetType="Grid" Property="IsVisible" Value="False">
                                                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="0" />
                                            </Trigger>
                                        </Grid.Triggers>
                                        <!-- the loading content -->
                                        <ActivityIndicator
                                            IsRunning="true"
                                            Color="Black"
                                            WidthRequest="20"
                                            HeightRequest="20"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ListView.Footer>
                            </ListView>
                        </local:AccordionView.SubTemplate>
                    </local:AccordionView.Template>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:AccordionView>
        </StackLayout>
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this.